# How to fix lagging background-attachment:fixed in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

**Trouble**: I have on site few parallax blocks, here is one of them:

```
<section data-original="img/purity.jpg" class="special-soft lazy module parallax parallax-window_2 cf"
       id="quality">
    <div class="special-soft__text cf">
      <span class="f_left">01</span>
      <h2 class="f_left">ОСОБЛИВА М'ЯКІСТЬ</h2>
      <hr class="f_left">
      <p class="f_left">
        Особливість м'якого смаку класичної горілки Medoff досягається завдяки унікальній технології фільтрації
        «медовий дощ». Смак напою дозріває під впливом мікрочастинок меду, який вважається кращим природним
        фільтром
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

section.special-soft {
  position: relative;
  height: 722px;
  background: url("../img/purity.jpg") no-repeat scroll center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background-image 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: background-image 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background-image 0.4s;
  transition: background-image 0.4s;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari i am getting lags

**Question**: How may i solve it? I need better performance in Safari

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/z7b0fsx9/

Thanks you

Comment: Please create a fiddle so that we can see the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman did it

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the CSS attribute that causes the performance variance between Safari and the other browsers. One approach is to comment out one or more of the "section.special-soft" CSS class attributes. I would start with the -webkit-font-smoothing attribute.

Also, consider applying at least some of the "special-soft" CSS class attributes to the enclosed div tag instead of the section tag. The section tag is new to HTML5, but the div tag existed prior to HTML5.